# How to stop or suspend polling after batch job fail?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

We use spring-batch-integration to process .json files from directory. It's necessary to stop processing after failure, to find out a problem (to change file with problem or other solutions) and then continue. Current configuration continue polling after error. How to change it? or maybe there are different approach for such scenario.

```
@Configuration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationConfig {

private @Autowired Job job;

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "jobChannel", 
   outputChannel = "errorChannel")
protected JobLaunchingMessageHandler launcher(JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
    return new JobLaunchingMessageHandler(jobLauncher);
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel fileInputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "fileInputChannel",
                       poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() {
    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    source.setDirectory(new File("C:/Temp/myfiles/"));
    source.setFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.json"));
    source.setScanEachPoll(true);
    source.setUseWatchService(true);
    return source;
}

@Transformer(inputChannel = "fileInputChannel",
             outputChannel = "jobChannel")
public JobLaunchRequest transform(File aFile) {
    String fileName = aFile.getAbsolutePath();
    JobParameters jobParameters =
    new JobParametersBuilder().addString("input.file.name", fileName)
            .addDate("dateTime", new Date()).toJobParameters();
    JobLaunchRequest request = new JobLaunchRequest(job, jobParameters);
    return request;
}
}
```

[example was from this article](https://keyholesoftware.com/2017/07/10/using-spring-integration-in-conjunction-with-spring-batch/)

neither outputChannel = "nullChannel" nor outputChannel = "errorChannel" helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop the inbound channel adapter.

You can autowire a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` which is registered by the `@InboundChannelAdapter` annotation.

When you detect the failure, call `stop()` on the adapter.

Comment: I got autowiring error, see my answer, what is correct way to autoware ?

Comment: You shouldn't add an answer to show more details; you should edit your question instead. Try making the adapter static: `public static MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() {` so it will be registered earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("fileInputChannel")
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel", 
  outputChannel = "nullChanel")
protected ErrorLogger errorLogger(JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
    return new ErrorLogger();
}
```

and

```
public class ErrorLogger {
private static final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(ErrorLogger.class);

@Autowired
private SourcePollingChannelAdapter fileInputChannel;


@ServiceActivator
public void logError(Message<JobExecution> message) {
    JobExecution msgex=message.getPayload();
     if (msgex.getStatus() == BatchStatus.FAILED) {
         logger.error("Exception " + 
         msgex.getExitStatus().getExitDescription());
         fileInputChannel.stop();
     }
}
}
```

But I get autowiring error in ErrorLogger

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'fileInputChannel'; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 
'org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter' 
available:
```

Seems like initialization order issue despite of **@DependsOn("fileInputChannel")**, because i can autoware it in separate controller without error.

It works only with

```
 @Autowired(required = false)
 private SourcePollingChannelAdapter fileInputChannel;
```